# SQL syntax highlighting 

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, eclipse-plugin

For example, I have SQL statement:

```
 insert into Table(id, name) values (1, 'x');
```

When I'm cursor/mouse-over a column name (like `id`), then I'd like to have its corresponding value `1` highlighted.

Is there a tool or plugin for this?

I don't want to write a tool for it, but use an existing one if one exists.

**EDIT:
I added eclipse and visual-studio tags, because I use both of them and maybe there is some plugin.**

Comment: @Spooks someone has to write it, but I feel it should already exist ;)

Comment: @IAdapter I really hope someone has a plugin for microsoft servers, for large inserts that would be ridiculously helpful

Comment: @Spooks I hope I can inspire some amazing highlight-plugin programmer and maybe someone would make it :) this looks like a lot of math programming and I don't like that :(

Comment: Suggest it at http://connect.microsoft.com/sqlserver

Comment: @Matthew Burr I don't use SQL Server and I don't believe in suggestions. They are smarter and deep inside they know its a bad idea(and impossible for them to implement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know of a tool that does that.  For your simple example I doubt you really even need that.  However, you really need it when you have many columns (which I guess is the real reason for the question), and this is how I handle it:

```
--format your large insert statements like this
insert YourTableName
        (col1      , col2      , col3   , col4     , col5
        ,col6      , col7      , col8   , col9     , col10
        ,col11     , col12     , col13  , col14    , col15
        ,col16     , col17)
    VALUES
        (1         , '2'       , 3.0    , 4        , 'five'
        ,6         , 'seven'   , 8      , @nine    , 'ten'
        ,11.0      , 'twelve'  , 13     , @_14     , 15
        ,'sixteen' , 17)
```

you can better match the values to the columns than the same insert with minimal formatting:

```
insert YourTableName (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12, col13,col14, col15,col16,col17) VALUES (1, '2',3.0,4,'five',6,'seven',8,@nine, 'ten',11.0,'twelve',13,@_14,15,'sixteen',17)
```

This formatting is only worth it for production code, not throway one off inserts.

I have a simple stored procedures that outputs the columns of a given table.  Run in text mode, I can take that output, with SSMS's ability to cut/paste rectagle selections and can quickly fromat the column list section.  I duplicate that in the values list and over type the column names with the values.  This works well when the values are from a select query as well.

Comment: yes, you are right. I just didnt want to paste the real code. good idea with using formatter. I needed it when browsing a SQL dump.

Comment: Well said.  The formatting of SQL queries is something I would **fight** over.

Comment: @Abe Miessler but the SQL dump is generated by a tool and the tool is .... you know.